# Warning: Native component for "BVLinearGradient" does not exist

Tags: react-native, linear-gradients

I'm trying to implement [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) but I get the following error once I import the library into my react-native component:

```
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'
```

[image]

I can successfully compile the project in XCode and the gradient shows up on the physical iPhone but it doesn't in the Simulator.

Has anyone dealt with this problem before?

Again, the problem is that react-native (iOS Simulator) can't find the library but the BVLinearGradient library are there in Xcode and the project compiles successfully.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: did you also link it? `react-native link`

Comment: Yes I did and I reset the cache `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: You need to recompile the project, not just restart the packager. So quit the packager and re run `react-native run-ios`

Comment: could you resolve this?, i have the same issue and tried all of the above.

Comment: I only get this error when building for RELEASE. Debug works fine. Target iOS version 11.0.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using RN 0.6.x, so you don't have to link. You ought to `cd` into your `ios` directory and run this command.

```
"pod install"
```

And you should read [README](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient#link-the-library) of linear gradient carefully for [iOS integration](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient#link-the-library).